# Using 2 JOINS still display rows in table is rows in join table don't exist

Tags: mysql

I am running this query and the second join on `m2` is for ordering the results but i want to still show the rows from the `admin` table if the `website_order` row in `m2` doesn't exist

```
SELECT 
    a.sequence, 
    CONCAT(a.forename, ' ', a.surname) AS name, 
    a.position 
FROM 
    admin a 
JOIN 
    admin_meta m1 on a.sequence = m1.user 
JOIN 
    admin_meta m2 ON a.sequence = m2.user 
WHERE 
    a.disabled = '' AND 
    m1.field = 'display_on_website' AND 
    m1.value = '1' AND 
    m2.field = 'website_order' 
ORDER BY CAST(m2.value AS DECIMAL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `left join`:

```
SELECT 
    a.sequence, 
    CONCAT(a.forename, ' ', a.surname) AS name, 
    a.position 
FROM 
    admin a 
JOIN 
    admin_meta m1 on a.sequence = m1.user 
LEFT JOIN 
    admin_meta m2 ON a.sequence = m2.user AND m2.field = 'website_order'
WHERE 
    a.disabled = '' AND 
    m1.field = 'display_on_website' AND 
    m1.value = '1' 

ORDER BY CAST(m2.value AS DECIMAL)
```

Comment: ah yes! thank you. is it possible to order as the above but if the order row doesnt exist in `m2`, they show at the end?

Comment: @Charlie try something like `ORDER BY CAST(ifnull(m2.value,`99999`) AS DECIMAL)`